# Yii - Remove default controller from url

Tags: php, url, yii, module

I'm very new in Yii.

My question is in the subject. 
I have three modules, they all have a default Controller
I have the following URL : www.xxx.com/module/**default**/action

And I would like to have this : www.xxx.com/module/action

Please help me I can't figure it out, althought I have read a lot of topics about it, I don't understand them...

Thanks

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496869/yii-eliminate-default-controller-id-for-a-module-from-url

Answer (score 5):

if you are using modules inside your project you need to add these lines to remove defaulcontroller from url in you config url manager

```
 '<module:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:(.*?)>' => '<module>/default/<action>/<id>',
            '<module:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/default/<action>',
```